What is the second moment of a point process with stochastic intensity?
I consider $(N_t)_t$ a point process with intensity $(\lambda_t)_t$.
How can we write $\mathbb{E}[N_T^2]$ with $(\lambda_t)_t$ only?
What I manage to do is
$N_T^2 = 2 \int_0^T N_{t-} dN_t + N_T$ with Ito, so $$\mathbb{E}[N_T^2] = 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T N_{t-} \lambda_t dt\right]+ \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T \lambda_t dt\right]$$
But how to do better than that?
If $N_{t-}$ and $\lambda_t$ were independent like in the case where $(\lambda_t)_t$ is deterministic, then we could write
$$2 \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T N_{t-} \lambda_t dt\right] = \int_0^T \int_0^t \mathbb{E}\left[\lambda_s\right] ds \mathbb{E}\left[\lambda_t\right] dt = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T \lambda_t dt\right]^2,$$
but what about the general stochastic case?

By "$N$, $\lambda$ independent" do you mean only the case that $\lambda$ is deterministic? Because I don't see how the two can be independent otherwise - $N$ is defined in terms of $\lambda$!
